# Linux shared library woes

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have created a shared library, copied it to /usr/lib, run ldconfig (it shows up on the list when run with -v) and copied the .h file into /usr/include.
However when I try and use the lib #include , i get "Undefined Reference to 'Method1'.
What an I doing wrong?
My makefile has no special commands as all files are in the standard places.

Comment: linker's not magic. Use `-lMyLibrary` (lowercase L) to tell the linker to look for symbols in your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include` will include the header file when you compile your source code.

However you also need to link to your shared library. For most unix compilers, that is done with the `-l flag`

For a shared library with the name `libFoo.so` , use the flag `-lFoo` when linking your program.

Comment: I was trying to be clever and included the #pragma GCC visibility(hidden) around the whole file and this removed the functions I needed to be exposed - user error as usual!